# Having 3 conditions in JPA criteria query

Tags: java, jpa, criteria

I need to pick all pending bookings from next hour till next two hours. I have criteria like this:

```
calendar.setTime(new Date());
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
    cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(bookingRoot.<Date>get("pickupTime"), calendar.getTime()));
    calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
    cq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(bookingRoot.get("status"), CabStatus.PENDING), cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(bookingRoot.<Date>get("pickupTime"), calendar.getTime())));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

But it picks all bookings having pickup time less than than the time after 2 hours. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your first cb.and(...) is not in the where- part. You should make something like that:

```
calendar.setTime(new Date());
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
Predicate greater = cb.and(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(bookingRoot.<Date>get("pickupTime"),calendar.getTime()));
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
Predicat lower = cb.and(cb.equal(bookingRoot.get("status"), CabStatus.PENDING), cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(bookingRoot.<Date>get("pickupTime"), calendar.getTime())));
cq.where(cb.and(greater,lower);
return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).getResultList();
```

You can use system.out.println to see the query that JPA create:

```
 TypedQuery<ENTITYTYPE> typedQuery = em.createQuery(cq);
 System.out.println(typedQuery);
    return typedQuery.getResultList()
```